# Sticky header in RecyclerView with multiple view types not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create a recyclerView with StaggeredGridLayoutManager which contains 4 types of views, namely a header which should stick at top, a card element, a horizontal scrolling ribbon, a loading indicator. All of this works fine if except the sticky header part. I am using [header-decor](https://github.com/edubarr/header-decor) library for the sticky header functionality. Here is my adapter:

```
public class StickyFeedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements StickyHeaderAdapter<StickyFeedAdapter.HeaderViewHolder> {

    protected final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
    private Context context;
    private List<FeedItems> feedItems;
    private Fragment fragment;
    String API;
    private String token;
    TinyDB tinyDB;
    RestAdapter restAdapter;
    private static int radius = Utils.dpToPx(28);
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    GApplication application;
    MixpanelAPI mixpanel;

    private static final int ITEM_TYPE_HEADER = 0, ITEM_TYPE_CARD = 1, ITEM_TYPE_RIBBON = 2, ITEM_TYPE_LOADING = 3;

    public StickyFeedAdapter(Context context, List<FeedItems> list, Fragment fragment) {
        this.context = context;
        this.feedItems = list;
        this.fragment = fragment;

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        application = (GApplication) ((AppCompatActivity) context).getApplication();
        API = application.getAPI();
        mixpanel = MixpanelAPI.getInstance(context, application.getMixpanelId());
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        tinyDB = new TinyDB(context);
        token = tinyDB.getString(AppConstants.ACCESS_TOKEN);
        RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                request.addHeader("Authorization", "Token " + token);
            }
        };
        restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient))
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setEndpoint(API)
                .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LogUtil.i(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder called");
        if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_HEADER) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.feed_row, parent, false);
            return new HeaderViewHolder(view);
        } else if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_CARD) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.feed_new_card, parent, false);
            return new CardViewHolder(view);
        } else if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_RIBBON) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.feed_row_ribbon, parent, false);
            return new RibbonViewHolder(view, context);
        } else if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_LOADING) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_loading, parent, false);
            return new LoadingViewHolder(view);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        LogUtil.i(TAG, "onBindViewHolder called");
        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
        FeedItems currentItem = getItem(position);
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();

        if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_HEADER) {
            final HeaderItem headerItem = currentItem.getHeaderItem();
            layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);

            if (headerItem.isFollowing()) {
                ((HeaderViewHolder) holder).mightLike.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ((HeaderViewHolder) holder).followButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_background_filled);
                ((HeaderViewHolder) holder).followText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#424447"));
                ((HeaderViewHolder) holder).followText.setText("FOLLOWING");
            } else {
                ((HeaderViewHolder) holder).mightLike.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ((HeaderViewHolder) holder).followButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_background);
                ((HeaderViewHolder) holder).followText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F0F0E9"));
                ((HeaderViewHolder) holder).followText.setText("FOLLOW");
            }

            ((HeaderViewHolder) holder).followButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (!headerItem.isFollowing()) {
                        //follow gallery
                        headerItem.setFollowing(true);
                        ((HeaderViewHolder) holder).mightLike.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        ((HeaderViewHolder) holder).followButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_background_filled);
                        ((HeaderViewHolder) holder).followText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#424447"));
                        ((HeaderViewHolder) holder).followText.setText("FOLLOWING");

                        follow(headerItem.getGalleryPk());

                    } else {
                        //unfollow gallery
                        headerItem.setFollowing(false);
                        ((HeaderViewHolder) holder).mightLike.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        ((HeaderViewHolder) holder).followButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_background);
                        ((HeaderViewHolder) holder).followText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F0F0E9"));
                        ((HeaderViewHolder) holder).followText.setText("FOLLOW");

                        unfollow(headerItem.getGalleryPk());
                    }
                }
            });

            ((HeaderViewHolder) holder).shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });

            ((HeaderViewHolder) holder).galleryName.setText(headerItem.getGalleryName());

            ((HeaderViewHolder) holder).numPhotos.setText(String.format("%s PHOTOS", String.valueOf(headerItem.getNumPhotos())));

            ((HeaderViewHolder) holder).numFollowers.setText(String.format("%s FOLLOWERS", String.valueOf(headerItem.getNumFollowers())));

        } else if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_CARD) {
            final FeedPhoto cardItem = currentItem.getCardItem();
            layoutParams.setFullSpan(false);

            double aspectRatio = (double) cardItem.getWidth() / cardItem.getHeight();
            ((CardViewHolder) holder).image.setAspectRatio((float) aspectRatio);

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(cardItem.getPhotoUrl());
            ImageRequest request = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(uri)
                    .setProgressiveRenderingEnabled(true)
                    .build();
            DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                    .setImageRequest(request)
                    .setOldController(((CardViewHolder) holder).image.getController())
                    .build();
            ((CardViewHolder) holder).image.setController(controller);

            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(cardItem.getProfilePic())
                    .resize(radius, radius)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .transform(new CircleTransform())
                    .into(((CardViewHolder) holder).profilePic);

            ((CardViewHolder) holder).username.setText(cardItem.getUserName());

            ((CardViewHolder) holder).timestamp.setText(cardItem.getTime());

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(cardItem.getLocation())) {
                ((CardViewHolder) holder).locationBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                ((CardViewHolder) holder).locationBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ((CardViewHolder) holder).locationText.setText(cardItem.getLocation());
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(cardItem.getCaption())) {
                ((CardViewHolder) holder).captionText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                ((CardViewHolder) holder).captionText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ((CardViewHolder) holder).captionText.setText(cardItem.getCaption());
            }

            ((CardViewHolder) holder).collectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AddToCollectionActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("photoPk", cardItem.getPk());
                    intent.putExtra("imageUrl", cardItem.getPhotoUrl());
                    intent.putExtra("location", cardItem.getLocation());
                    intent.putExtra("caption", cardItem.getCaption());
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                    ((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.no_change);
                }
            });

        } else if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_RIBBON) {
            RibbonItem ribbonItem = currentItem.getRibbonItem();
            layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);

            FeedRibbonAdapter feedRibbonAdapter = new FeedRibbonAdapter(context, fragment, ribbonItem);
            ((RibbonViewHolder) holder).feedRibbonAdapter = feedRibbonAdapter;

            ((RibbonViewHolder) holder).ribbonText.setText(ribbonItem.getTitle());
            ((RibbonViewHolder) holder).recyclerView.setAdapter(feedRibbonAdapter);

        } else if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_LOADING) {
            layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);
            ((LoadingViewHolder) holder).indicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public FeedItems getItem(int position) {
        return feedItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        LogUtil.i(TAG, "getItemViewType called");
        FeedItems currentItem = getItem(position);
        if (currentItem.getType() == 0) {
            return ITEM_TYPE_HEADER;
        } else if (currentItem.getType() == 1) {
            return ITEM_TYPE_CARD;
        } else if (currentItem.getType() == 2) {
            return ITEM_TYPE_RIBBON;
        } else {
            return ITEM_TYPE_LOADING;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return feedItems == null ? 0 : feedItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getHeaderId(int position) {
        LogUtil.i(TAG, "getHeaderId called");
        if (position == 0) { // don't show header for first item
            return StickyHeaderDecoration.NO_HEADER_ID;
        } else {
            return getHeaderForPosition(position);
        }
    }

    private long getHeaderForPosition(int position) {
        for (int i = position; i > 0; i--) {
            if (getItem(position) != null) {
                if (getItem(position).getType() == 0) {
                    return (long) i;
                }
            }
        }

        return StickyHeaderDecoration.NO_HEADER_ID;
    }

    @Override
    public HeaderViewHolder onCreateHeaderViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
        LogUtil.i(TAG, "onCreateHeaderViewHolder called");
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_row, parent, false);
        return new HeaderViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(final HeaderViewHolder viewholder, int position) {
        LogUtil.i(TAG, "onBindHeaderViewHolder called");
        FeedItems currentItem = getItem(position);
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) viewholder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
        final HeaderItem headerItem = currentItem.getHeaderItem();
        layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);

        if (headerItem.isFollowing()) {
            viewholder.mightLike.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewholder.followButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_background_filled);
            viewholder.followText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#424447"));
            viewholder.followText.setText("FOLLOWING");
        } else {
            viewholder.mightLike.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewholder.followButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_background);
            viewholder.followText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F0F0E9"));
            viewholder.followText.setText("FOLLOW");
        }

        viewholder.followButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!headerItem.isFollowing()) {
                    //follow gallery
                    headerItem.setFollowing(true);
                    viewholder.mightLike.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    viewholder.followButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_background_filled);
                    viewholder.followText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#424447"));
                    viewholder.followText.setText("FOLLOWING");

                    follow(headerItem.getGalleryPk());

                } else {
                    //unfollow gallery
                    headerItem.setFollowing(false);
                    viewholder.mightLike.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewholder.followButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_background);
                    viewholder.followText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F0F0E9"));
                    viewholder.followText.setText("FOLLOW");

                    unfollow(headerItem.getGalleryPk());
                }
            }
        });

        viewholder.shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        viewholder.galleryName.setText(headerItem.getGalleryName());

        viewholder.numPhotos.setText(String.format("%s PHOTOS", String.valueOf(headerItem.getNumPhotos())));

        viewholder.numFollowers.setText(String.format("%s FOLLOWERS", String.valueOf(headerItem.getNumFollowers())));
    }

    public static class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @Bind(R.id.mightLike)
        TextView mightLike;

        @Bind(R.id.galleryName)
        TextView galleryName;

        @Bind(R.id.shareButton)
        RelativeLayout shareButton;

        @Bind(R.id.shareText)
        TextView shareText;

        @Bind(R.id.followButton)
        RelativeLayout followButton;

        @Bind(R.id.followText)
        TextView followText;

        @Bind(R.id.numPhotos)
        TextView numPhotos;

        @Bind(R.id.numFollowers)
        TextView numFollowers;

        public HeaderViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        }
    }

    public static class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @Bind(R.id.profilePic)
        ImageView profilePic;

        @Bind(R.id.username)
        TextView username;

        @Bind(R.id.timestamp)
        TextView timestamp;

        @Bind(R.id.image)
        SimpleDraweeView image;

        @Bind(R.id.tagButton)
        ImageView tagButton;

        @Bind(R.id.reminderButton)
        ImageView reminderButton;

        @Bind(R.id.collectButton)
        RelativeLayout collectButton;

        @Bind(R.id.shareButton)
        RelativeLayout shareButton;

        @Bind(R.id.locationBox)
        LinearLayout locationBox;

        @Bind(R.id.locationText)
        TextView locationText;

        @Bind(R.id.captionText)
        TextView captionText;

        public CardViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }

    public static class RibbonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @Bind(R.id.recyclerView)
        FlingRecyclerView recyclerView;

        @Bind(R.id.ribbonText)
        TextView ribbonText;

        FeedRibbonAdapter feedRibbonAdapter;

        public RibbonViewHolder(View view, Context context) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            SpacesItemDecoration spacesItemDecoration = new SpacesItemDecoration(Utils.dpToPx(8));
            recyclerView.addItemDecoration(spacesItemDecoration);
        }
    }

    public static class LoadingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @Bind(R.id.avloadingIndicatorView)
        AVLoadingIndicatorView indicator;

        public LoadingViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        }
    }

    private static class SpacesItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
        private int space;

        public SpacesItemDecoration(int space) {
            this.space = space;
        }

        @Override
        public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
            int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
            int count = state.getItemCount();
            if (position == 0) {
                outRect.left = space;
                outRect.right = space / 2;
            } else if (position == count - 1) {
                outRect.right = space;
                outRect.left = space / 2;
            } else {
                outRect.left = space / 2;
                outRect.right = space / 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, the header doesn't stick. It behaves normally. I tried logging the function calls and fount out that getHeaderId() isn't getting called. What could be the reason for that? If anyone has tried this library, does it work with multiple view types? Any help would be highly appreciated.